# How to Develop Codeigniter Admin Panel

Tags: codeigniter

Hi i'm new to codeigniter.
I have developed this website using CI.
http://maxmovies.in/fattto

Now i want to create the admin panel for this website.

I want the url like this to access the admin panel.
http://maxmovies.in/fattto/admin/

First i thought adding a admin controller and proceed with that. 
But my back-end will have around 25 pages.
I don't think adding 25 functions in the single controller is not
good idea.

I searched and got some tutorial but i'm not clear with that.

So can any one help me to config the admin panel for my website?

Thanks to all and sorry for if my english is not good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create fattto/admin folder in controller view and module and set all code in this folder 
when u write http://maxmovies.in/fattto/admin/  it open admin panel whatever code u write

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'l do it as you said and inform you it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could [organise your controllers into sub-folders](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#subfolders), which would give you the desired effect.

The use of [Routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) could also help you achieve what you want, which will allow you to map a URL to a particular controller/method.